# How to create a insert statement based on the input of different type of tables?

Tags: mysql, python-3.6, sql-insert

I have written a function that uses mysql connector to insert data to table in mysql.

```
def insert_row(data, table, conn):
    """Insert new row  of data receieved.
    """
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = ("INSERT INTO " + table + " "
    "(temp, humidity)"
    " VALUES (%(temp)s, %(humidity)s)")
    print(query)
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

However, now I want to modify it to be able to build query dynamically based on table and its columns coming from the data.
the `data` arg is a `dict` object.

currently statement that gets constructed is this `INSERT INTO particle_photon (temp, humidity) VALUES (%(temp)s, %(humidity)s)` but different table may have different columns coming in the `data` dict object.

Comment: Do you want to fetch table columns dynamically or you pass them along the function parameters? Anyway it looks like you're missing a tag for python (it's python, isn't it?) because this question isn't just about MySQL.

Comment: I pass them along the function parameters. yes python3.6 to be specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out myself,

```
def insert_row(data, table, conn):
    """Insert new row  of data receieved.
    """
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    placeholder = ", ".join(["%s"] * len(data))
    stmt = "insert into `{table}` ({columns}) values ({values});".format(
        table=table, 
        columns=",".join(data.keys()), 
        values=placeholder
        )
    cursor.execute(stmt, list(data.values()))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove column names and the parenthesis around them from your prepared query, then include them again in your table parameter. So the table would be equal to `particle_photon (temp, humidity)` instead of just `particle_photon`.

Comment: I don't think if you understood what I asked, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I do not want to specify table name and column names.

Comment: so would you tell me where did I misidentify? @Ciastopiekarz